# "The type does not include any accessible constructors" - has parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to load a class as a static resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <myControls:HelpTip x:Key="NavagationHT" Message="Test help tip message for navagation" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And I'm getting the error "The type HelpTip does not include any accessible constructors". However, the class is public, and has a parameterless constructor that should be accessible:

```
public class HelpTip : PropertyChangedBase
{
    ...

    public HelpTip()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        HelpTipManager.AddHelpTip(this);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of anything else that could be causing this error?

**Edit:** It's resolved now. I'm not sure how or why, maybe there were some problems elsewhere that was causing the code to be looking up an old version where there was no parameterless constructor?

Comment: Does you base class `PropertyChangedBase` have one too?

Comment: Good idea, but yes it does: public PropertyChangedBase();

Comment: Could it be possible that it finds some other HelpTip class instead?

Comment: Don't think so, but it seems to be resolved now. I suspect it was because of errors elsewhere, maybe it wasn't using the latest code?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, There didn't appear to be any solution posted as of yet.  I added a parameter-less constructor, but the design mode doesn't seem to have registered that I made that change and still gives an error even though I've cleaned and rebuilt the project several times after adding the parameter-less constructor. The clr namespace is correct and there is no base class...

Comment: I get this on a regular basis as well.  "The type has no accessible constructors".  WELL I'M LOOKING RIGHT AT ONE, WTH????  Guessing it's Visual Studio oddness.  Because that NEVER happens...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment on the question, I run into this, as well, on a regular basis.  I am using Visual Studio 2015, Update 3.

I just resolved this (for now) by closing the solution, and Visual Studio, then removing the bin and obj folders from the project my XAML file was in, then re-opening VS, the solution and doing a Clean All and Rebuild All (something I generally do anyway, as I've been burned by stale project builds in the past.

Not a **great** answer, per se, but it allowed me to continue working, so at least it's a viable workaround.  Hopefully it'll work for other people as well.

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio worked for me. I didn't have to delete the bin/obj folders, but I had done a Rebuild before the restart.

Comment: I also managed this by switching to release mode and then back to debug, then doing another build.

Answer (score 1):

Restart VS works for me, without cleaning. rebuilding and bin removing.

I'm using VS v. 15.5.7