# The type "SettingsViewModel" does not include any accessible constructors. Is there a way to get rid of this error?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

I'm making a simple application with WPF and binding one of the windows to a view model. The view model needs a few references at run-time to get the data it needs, so my view model has a constructor with parameters. I also have a parameter-less constructor to use during design to test the look of the window.

The problem I'm running in to is that whenever a constructor with parameters exists visual studio displays the error:

'The type "SettingsViewModel" does not include any accessible constructors.'

If I comment out the run-time constructor then no errors occur and everything works as expected.

Additionally, I've tried making the run-time constructor private and exposing it through a factory method, which had no effect. I've tried commenting out code-behind code referencing the second constructor. I've also tried cleaning the solution, restarting visual studio, then rebuilding.

So far the only thing I have found to work is commenting out the run-time constructor and any references to it. Also just to be clear I am not using the SettingsViewModel instance for anything yet, at this point I'm just trying to define it as a resource.

SettingsWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SettingsViewModel x:Key="DevelopTimeModel" />
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2 3"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
```

SettingsWindow.xaml.cs

```
        public SettingsWindow(Autodesk.Revit.UI.UIApplication app)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SettingsViewModel viewModel = SettingsViewModel.GetRuntimeViewModel(app, this);
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
            MainListBox.SelectionChanged += (o, e) => viewModel.RefreshCommands();
        }
```

SettingViewModel.cs

```
        public SettingsViewModel()
        {
           //creation of design-time data here
        }

        public static SettingsViewModel GetRuntimeViewModel(UIApplication app, SettingsWindow settingsWindow)
        {
            return null;// new SettingsViewModel(app, settingsWindow);
        }


        private SettingsViewModel(UIApplication app, SettingsWindow settingsWindow)
        {
            ContextRouter = new RevitContextRouter(app, this.ToString());
            members.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => NotifyPropertyChanged("Members." + e.PropertyName);
            Commands = new SettingsCommands(this);
            LoadSettings();
            SettingsWindowRef = settingsWindow;
            settingsWindow.Closed += (s,e) => SaveSettings() ;
        }
```

Any help getting rid of this error message and similar ones when they come up would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36981415/the-type-does-not-include-any-accessible-constructors-has-parameterless-cons) it can just be a Visual Studio issue. Does restarting VS or removing the binary folders fix anything?

Comment: I just tried closing visual studio, removing the binary files, then restarting. It seems the error is unaffected.

Comment: Is your SettingsViewModel class set to public?

Comment: Both the SettingsViewModel class and my window are set to public. Error goes away when second constructor is removed, so I am led to believe that default constructor is accessible.

Comment: Why would you define a view model as a resource?

Comment: I want to use d:DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DevelopTimeModel}" to preview what the window looks like with sample data while designing the form. It's mainly to prevent the need to launch the window every time I want to preview (launching from another application so tedious).

Comment: @How about `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:DevelopTimeModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}`?

Comment: That seems useful for binding a separate mock class during design time and I'll probably end up doing something similar if I can't get binding to work with an instance of my current view model. The main thing I want to answer is why having multiple constructors is causing an error in the designer.

Comment: I just tested your solution for linking a design time data model. It seems to be working. Whatever problem is happening when declaring an instance of my view model seems to only happen when declaring it as a resource.